# How to save a macro enabled workbook (xlsm) with Excel interop?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I get  the following error when trying to save an Excel workbook with the `xlsm` extension:

> This extension can not be used with the selected file type. Change the
> file extension in the File name text box or select a different file
> type by changing the Save as type.

My code:

```cs
public static void CreateExcelfile()
{
    Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
    oWB.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\konanki\\Documents\\Sample.xlsm", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    oWB.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
}
```

Comment: I am getting Error for the below code.Error: This extension can not be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the File name text box or select a different file type by changing the Save as type.

Comment: it works with xls but not with xlsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not providing the file format in the `SaveAs` call. In your case you need to specify the `XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` for xlsm. Also, note that the use of `Missing.Value` is unnecessary for all optional parameters since they have default values. This should work:

```
public static void CreateExcelfile()
{
    Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
    oWB.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\konanki\\Documents\\Sample.xlsm", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, AccessMode: XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
    oWB.Close(true);
}
```

Comment: Solution worked thanks a lot